# FileReader vs FormData for uploading a file using websockets?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, websocket, filereader, form-data

Is there any benefit in using FileReader over FormData for uploading files using websockets in JavaScript?

Any performance advantages?
Any preference based on other traits?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish because these two objects are used for different purposes.

From Mozilla about FileReader API

> The **FileReader** object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

From Mozilla about FormData

> The **FormData** object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send
> using XMLHttpRequest

In other words, you want to use the FileReader API to read files on the client-side. You don't have to have a server for processing the file because many operations such as image tweaking and others are supported in the browser. However, if you need to save the file on the server for future use, you will need to send the file across the network, and this is where the FormData object comes in. After you've read the file, you can encode it using FormData and send it to the server.